# foursquare api - I can't create new application

Tags: foursquare

I am trying to create an app on foursquare. I fill up everything except the "Install options" section and i submit the form. Then i am getting this response (saw that through chrome dev tools) :

```
{"meta":{"code":403,"errorType":"other","errorDetail":"Form code invalid.","requestId":"54ea4fa7498ea21416da93df"},"notifications":[{"type":"notificationTray","item":{"unreadCount":0}}],"response":{}}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Same issue on new foursquare account while it still works with an older one. No solution so far :(

Comment: I reached out to Foursquare on twitter and it appears they are on it : https://twitter.com/foursquareAPI/status/572408695981772800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just received an answer to my request to the foursquare API team. It was an issue affecting some new accounts. It should be fixed now. If you are still facing any issues you can contact them (they are answering on Twitter).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like email sign in is broken and won't let you create apps (even if your account is new). Instead I used a Facebook account and the issue is gone (I've tried with G+ and it works), maybe there is some kind of account restrictions since the HTTP response code is 403.

Comment: I tried to link a facebook account to my foursquare account and then to login with it,but it doesn't work either.