# Foursquare Developer: Cannot create App

Tags: foursquare

For our app I need to include Foursquare API. In order to get the API key I registered a new user and tried to register a new app. But whenever I hit the save button I get the dialog "The app is being saved" and nothing happens. Its just stuck there. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663870/foursquare-api-i-cant-create-new-application Looks like they are working on fixing the issue: https://twitter.com/foursquareAPI/status/572408695981772800